# Using variable to name Excel column to turn into a list

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Why can I not import an excel column into a list when I put the name of the column as a variable but am able to when I just type out the name inside quotes? And how to fix it?

this gives "Exception thrown c211" error message:

```
s=c211
df = pd.read_excel('Info.xlsx', sheet_name=0)
sec1 = df[s].tolist()
```

this works:

```
df = pd.read_excel('Info.xlsx', sheet_name=0)
sec1 = df['c211'].tolist()
```

Also the exact code I need it for is

```
def intoList():
    s = ''.join(map(str, n))
    # n=[c,21,1] and s='c211'
    df = pd.read_excel('Info.xlsx', sheet_name=0)
    sec1 = df[s].tolist()
```

Comment: Try `s="c211"`?

Comment: String literals like `c211` need to have quotes around them, otherwise they will be interpreted as a variable.

Comment: @findwindow I tried to put quotes around but with no result

Comment: @findwindow I tried both 'c211' and "c211"

Comment: I don't know python or pandas so perhaps there's some syntax I am unaware of :/

Comment: `df = pd.read_excel('Info.xlsx', sheet_name=0)` will return a DataFrame which uses the values in the first row as column names. `df['column_name']` with single or double qoutes is how you get a single column from that DataFrame. Of course, you can also assign the string to a variable (so: `s='c211'` (again: use quotes!)), and then use `df[s]`. If no such column exists, you will get an error message: `KeyError: 'c211'`. If this is the case, inspect your `df` (e.g. `print(df.columns)`) and check if the result makes sense.